# Java String regex replace methods remove backslashes from replacement

Tags: java, regex, string

I just lost 1 hour to track what I consider not normal behaviour
with `replaceAll/replaceFirst` in the String class.

If there is a backslash in the replacement String then they are removed when
replacing. I then read that you can use `Matcher.quoteReplacement(String)` to
create a proper replacement string,but my question is why? I can expect that
the first argument should be escaped with `Patter.quote(String)` if you don't
want the special meaning but I don't see a reason to change the replacement :(

Yes **I will start using replace(CharSequence,CharSequence), just want to know why** :)

Here is an example that clearly shows the "strange" behaviour:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String out = "\\\\test\\\\";
    System.out.println(out);
    String result = "a".replaceAll("a", out);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

note how second line is with only single backslashes as opposed to two like in the first line

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement(java.lang.String)

Comment: Yes I read the docs after seeing the problem and found about Matcher.quoteReplacement but this doesn't explain the fact that this seems to be against http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment at least for me :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is true that backslash needs to be doubly escaped as the first argument in `String#replaceAll`.

**Reason:**

It is due to the fact that your replacement String can contain `back-references` like `$1`, `$2` etc even replacement text is also processed by underlying `regex engine` hence the need for double escaping same as the first argument, as you have also found out.

Answer (score 2):

As has been mentioned, the replacement string uses `$` characters to reference capture groups.

Therefore, to insert a literal `$`, you need to escape it with a `\`.

You can see this in the [source](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/regex/Matcher.java#Matcher.appendReplacement%28java.lang.StringBuffer%2Cjava.lang.String%29).

I'm not sure why they didn't use `$$` like .Net does.